# Uniform convergent trigonometric series

Tags: calculus

If $f:[-\pi, \pi] \rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is the value of an uniform convergent trigonometric series, can I then deduce that the $2\pi$-periodic normalized extension is an uniform convergent trigonometric series?

Comment: I am not sure whether the notation you use is totally standard. Well, even if it is I am pretty sure that people (like me) could answer your question if you made clearer what you mean by every word.

Comment: The following is true: if a series $\sum_n (a_n \cos nx+b_n\sin nx)$ converges uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi]$, then it converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$. Whether or not this answers your question  I can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

A trigonometric series that converges uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi]$ also converges uniformly on all of $\mathbb R$.  Its sum is obviously a $2\pi$ periodic function. Therefore, the answer is yes: if $f$ is the sum of a uniformly convergent trigonometric series, then so is the $2\pi$-periodic extension of $f$.